# Difference between a service and a method?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I know a service is a self contained functionality ,now if anyone creates a service following the rest principles then it can be called as a rest service. Now my question is ,if I create a Asp.Net web API project with a controller and several actions like getEmployee(), getEmployeeAddress(int id) actions and so on. then the client will consume it with a url say http://www.aaa.com/employee , then can i say the Action method getEmployee is a service and getEmployeeAddress which is consumed with the url http://www.aaa.com/employee/1 is another service.
or should i say i am offering a single employee management service which has multiple functionalities???

Answer (score 1):

A single webservice `EmployeeService` with multiple action methods configured with different url's. Services can be created based on the module, since `getEmployee` and `getEmployeeAddress` are related to employees, they can be added as action methods within `EmployeeService`. Also, I am not sure about the plan to have employee address as different endpoint instead of a list object within `Employee` object. Nevertheless, you can have multiple `GET` actions within a service.

1. Read all the employees

Url: `/employee`

Operation: `GET`

2. Read a single employee

Url: `/employee/{id}`

Operation: `GET`

3. Read a employee address(es)

Url: `/employee/{id}/address`

Operation: `GET`

For multiple GET operations (obviously with different method names other than default such as `1. GET`), make sure you have different url's assigned in the `[Route("url")]` or `[HttpGet("url")]` attributes of the action methods.

Additional points, pass the additional information not directly related to the operation such as using paging or sorting in the resultset, via query strings in the url's such as `/employee?page=1`